# Case Page Layout not showing for a specified profile

Tags: page-layout, record-type

I've created a Record Type for Cases, then a new Page Layout and assigned it to a specific Profile.  This doesn't seem to work, when I log in as a user, I still get the same old Case Page.  Any insight is appreciated.

[image: Case Page Layouts]

Comment: The one in question in particular is the TechOps Case Page Layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason even though I had "TechOps Case Page Layout" assigned for the profile, it was defaulting to the "Case Feed Layout".  I ended up going into the Profile->App permissions and removing "Use Case Feed" permission, and now it defaults to the one I want.